# Setting Action Listener and changing background

Tags: java, swing

I've created 3 buttons. They are each displayed twice in a JFrame. I'm having trouble changing the background of the frame. I've set ActionListeners but upon clicking, nothing is changing. May I ask for some help.

```
public class MyButtons extends JPanel {
    public static JFrame frame;
    private JButton Red = new JButton("Red");
    private JButton Green = new JButton("Green");
    private JButton Blue = new JButton("Blue");

    public void InitializeButton()
    {       
        Blue.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
            frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
          }
        });

        Green.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
            frame.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
          }
        });

        Red.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
            frame.setBackground(Color.RED);
          }
        });
    }

    public MyButtons()  {       
        InitializeButton();
        add(Red);
        add(Green);
        add(Blue);      
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame();


        JPanel row1 = new MyButtons();
        JPanel row2 = new MyButtons();

        row1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 100));
        row2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 100));

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        frame.add(row1);
        frame.add(row2);
        frame.pack();        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

   }
```

Comment: It seems the 1) frame is entirely covered by the panels, or 2) The call to `setBackground(..)` is not being passed to the content pane of the frame. - It would be a better strategy to add the two panels to a third panel to which you keep a reference and change the BG of..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your ActionListeners. The problem lies in the fact that the background of your ContentPane is covered by the GridLayout. Try it out by running your program, pressing any button and then resizing the JFrame. You will see the background color for a fraction of time until it resizes. If your graphics card is too fast for that, add something like: System.out.println(frame.getBackground().getBlue()); to your Blue ActionListener. Every time you press Blue it should print 255. 
I would add an empty third panel to the GridLayout and change its color instead of frame's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works, but probably not as you expected:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyButtons extends JPanel {

    //public static JFrame frame;
    // static is rarely a solution of problems in a GUI. ToDo! Change!
    static JPanel ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 0, 20, 20));

    private JButton Red = new JButton("Red");
    private JButton Green = new JButton("Green");
    private JButton Blue = new JButton("Blue");

    public void InitializeButton() {
        Blue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ui.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });

        Green.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ui.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        });

        Red.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ui.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        });
    }

    public MyButtons() {
        InitializeButton();
        add(Red);
        add(Green);
        add(Blue);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel row1 = new MyButtons();
        JPanel row2 = new MyButtons();

        //row1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 100));
        //row2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 100));

        //frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2,10,10));
        ui.add(row1);
        ui.add(row2);
        frame.add(ui);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

N.B. Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Thompson, what if I wanted it to be layered colors. For example, if red was pressed in the top Jpanel, it'd display red for top half, the bottom blue was pressed then blue would be on bottom half. Would there be a way for a button to affect eachother? For example if I select Red button, entire background should change to red.

Comment: Do you understand why that example only shows a band of color? Do you know how to change the size of it?